# Xcode - insertSubview:atIndex: not working as I expected it to

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, indexing, subview

I've been trying to use `insertSubview:atIndex:` to insert a subview under another one. The problem is that most of the time it's not the view with the higher index that is above, but the view that was added last. I noticed that this works fine if I pick indexes 0 and 1 but in my case one view needs to be at least at the index 12 and the other one needs to be above.

Here is some code as an example:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 100)];
label.text=@"LABEL";
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view insertSubview:label atIndex:13];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame=CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 100);
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view insertSubview:btn atIndex:12];
```

I know I could insert the label after the button but that wouldn't solve the problem in my case.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that you have more then 12 subviews?

Comment: I know in IB there is an option to Send to Back, which drops it to the very bottom of the view, allowing you to layer things, but not sure the exact call for it in code. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Nekto Does it matter how many subviews I already have? I don't get the logic of insert at index. If I inserted at index 1000 what would happen? I would have expected it to work like z-index in CSS, but that's obviously not the case.

Comment: Could you use alternate methods such as insertSubview:aboveSubview: or insertSubview:belowSubview:?

Comment: No belowSubview or aboveSubview won't work in my case...

Comment: I don't see what you are doing wrong unless you are re-using the same indexes at times in which case your view 12 or 13 might actually have new indexes?

Comment: I tried exactly this code in a new Blank View Based project and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t work like the CSS `z-index`—if a view has `k` subviews, inserting a view at any index higher than `k` will have the same effect as adding it at index `k`, or, in other words, adding it as the last (frontmost) subview. The subviews are maintained as a continuous list, not an arbitrarily-indexed array. In your case, you probably don’t have 14 subviews to start out with, so inserting one view at 13 and another at 12 isn’t having the effect you want.

Comment: So how can I manage to have one subview stay above all subviews added later without specifically placing those subviews below the one I want to be on top?

Comment: Instead of adding those subviews to the same view that your always-on-top subview is in, add them to a sibling of that overlay view. In other words, if you have view A, the parent view, and view C, the overlay view (a subview of A), place another subview, B, inside A and below C, then add the subviews you create later as children of B.

Comment: in HTML terms, that'd be `<A> <B> <X/> <Y/> <Z/> </B> <C/> </A>`, where X, Y, and Z are the other subviews you want to add later.

Comment: The problem is that I am working with a navigation controller so I have to push the view controllers every time their view is loaded in order to be able to pop back...